# Error with timezone into Google Forms with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, google-forms

I have a Google Forms with a date information like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l8bC.jpg)

This information I store into Google Spreadsheet along Google Apps Script; however in this spreadsheet, it doesn't store right date, it stores other date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7xy.jpg)

I use this Javascript code:

```
 var response = '2017-12-07 08:00'; //Value from Google Form
 var fecha_inicial = Utilities.formatString(response);
 fecha_inicial_Date = new Date(fecha_inicial.substr(0, 10) + "T" +
   fecha_inicial.substr(11, fecha_inicial.length)); //Thu Dec 07 2017 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

This form is executed in a gmail account in Spain.

Comment: By one side, Google Sheets and Google Apps Script have their own time zone settings by the other, it's not clear what is the problem you are referring. Is Google Form passing the wrong date to Google Sheets or are you using a script to pass the data from a form response to  Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

GMT-0500 is not Spain's time zone.  Spain is plus one.  So there is a 6 hour difference between GMT-0500 and your time zone.  To get your time zone:

```
var myTimeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();//Get the scripts time zone
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the question here is, how do I make the form date and the sheet date the same?

In the google sheet have you tried changing the format of the date column? Select the whole column and in the menu click Format -> Number and then choose the format you want.

If you want to manipulate the timestamp in the App script I recommend using the moment library - Mlj57Yi463PVmHumHxq4bkaUlUqvRc4KT then add this code to use it:

```
  var moment = Moment.moment
```